# Java regex to substring first 2 characters of a string

Tags: java, regex

I want to get the first two digits of a string using Java Regex. I don't want to use substring. For example: If my string has "12345", I want to substring "12" using regex.

Comment: Why? substring is far more efficient and easier to use for this simple case. Don't make your code complicated. Make it easy to read and understand and maintain.

Comment: What if you have "abc12345" ?

Comment: Let's say the input string is "c3hk45". Do you want "34" or "45"?

Comment: first two digit like this? `^(\d{2})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex

```
^\d{2}
```

`^` marks the beginning of string

`\d` matches a single digit

`{2}` is a quantifier which would match preceding pattern 2 times

---

```
string digits="";
Matcher m=Pattern.compile("^\d{2}").matcher();
if(m.find())digits=m.group();
```

Comment: The only time I would use regex in this scenario is because you have to, not because you can.

Comment: @SeanF haha..indeed..only if you **have** to but not if you can

Answer (score 2):

Better use `substring()` here

```
System.out.println("12345".substring(0,2)); // 12
```

Regex usually makes sense if you need to validate a complex input. Otherwise all the extra pattern compile stuff is unnecessary overhead. If you do indeed want to validate that your string is actually a number and return the first two digits you can still do it with the basic API.

```
String input = "12345";
try {
  Integer.parseInt(input);
  System.out.println(input.substring(0,2)); // 12
catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  System.out.println("Invalid input: " + input);
}
```

Comment: `xy12345` would return `xy` which are not digits..:)

Comment: @Anirudh It would print "xy" by the way. :)

Comment: @Anirudh No, the second index is exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this regex:

```
(?:\D+?)(\d{2})
```

Comment: Using this way it doesn't matter if you have something else in start of string instead of digits.

Answer (score 0):

regex for first two digit like this? `^(\d{2})`

or use something like `.*?(\d).*?(\d).*` if the string not only digit like c3hk45, then you can get those 2 digit from $1 and $2 then you will get 34